How can we set the exact current through feedback resistor Rf1 to achieve 0V output at DC?
In this type of circuit, how can we set the exact current flowing through the feedback resistor Rf1 to set the output at 0V at DC?

(The image is taken from this site)
The DC current of the two transistors TR2 and TR3 in the differential pair is straightforward and can be easily halved through R1. However, since the β of transistors TR2 and TR3 is not fixed and varies significantly, calculating Ib (of TR3) as Ic/β is not accurate.
This is the circuit I'm trying with a single power supply. The expected output should be half of VDD, or 25V, but the simulation does not produce this result.


You need to add a resistor (R12a) from Vdd to the Q2 base. This resistor needs to be equal to the R12 value.  And R12a||R12 = R14

@G36 It work but what would be the reason for that? Is there anything that could be improved?

Ideally (infinite gain), the current of Rf1 should be equal to the base current of the input TR2 transistor. It follows that if we want 0 V at the output, then with the same input transistors, the value of R4 must be the same as Rf1. In this case, the minimum output (DC) voltage is obtained if R4 is also 22 k. This does not change the gain.
In practice, this voltage will never be zero, but may be of the order of a few mV. The variation in the transistor parameters can be compensated relatively well by changing the value of R4 (offset compensation), but it will never be completely stable as a function of supply voltage and temperature.
Stability will be improved if TR2 and TR3 are dual PNP transistors (same fabrication, common package).
At single supply voltage, the base resistor of the input transistor should be connected to half the supply voltage instead of ground.

Your simulation has incorrect power applied: the diff pair inputs are referenced to GND, but your V- connection is also GND.  The amplifier simply cannot operate normally.  For a single-supply version, R12 needs to be a divider to halfway between supplies.
Single-supply circuits are discouraged, because they have huge startup settling time (with resulting "thump" in the speaker).  Especially with a 1000uF input coupling capacitor!
A combination parallel resistor capacitor divider can be used to make a virtual ground, and both input and output can be returned to it, restoring the bipolar supply scheme and eliminating "thump".
R18 = 1.2k is also a huge amount of bias current for a diff pair; normally it would be under 1mA (or >50k for supply as shown).  The corresponding base current has pulled up your input (R12, 120k) very far.
R12 and R14 values should match, so that when the diff pair is balanced (equal ICs), the base currents match, and the offsets on both resistors also match.  Input offset can be adjusted by varying the diff pair collector load resistor, R1.

Good tips but why do we want small current ~ 1mA?

Otherwise the input resistance is low (r_pi, see hybrid pi model), and input bias current very high, making hFE and resistor error that much more exaggerated. Low currents may also be used to optimize noise figure.

$$\color{red}{\boxed{\text{Answer given before OP changed question with a faulty circuit}}}$$

how can we set the exact current flowing through the feedback resistor
Rf1 to set the output at 0V at DC?

You are missing the main mechanism; the open-loop DC gain of the amplifier is high and, negative feedback (via Rf1) will ensure that the output is at 0 volts (to within a few millivolts). The DC voltage at the base of TR2 (0 volts) sets the demand for this control loop.

Thanks. I added a simulation file with a single power supply, but the output is not equal to half of VDD. How can I fix this?

@hana well, firstly, that's not the same circuit but, nevertheless, you should set your input signal to be 0 volts and wait for at least half a second (maybe longer) for things to settle down. I mean; look at the voltage on the base of TR2; it's meant to be 0 volts. Try running a proper transient simulation with no input voltage level.

Thanks, actually it's dc operating point simulation so capacitors are open circuit.
